# trigger an angular function when option selected from drop down

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-select

I am populating a select dropdown menu by making a call to an api. When the user chooses an option from the select menu I wish to fire the second function - `$scope.getRoles()`. However, this is firing immediately. Any ideas why this is happening? Please see my attempted code below.

**html**

```
<select>
     <option ng-change="getRoles()" ng-repeat="country in countries">{{ country.countryCode }}</option>   
</select>
```

**angular**

```
app.controller("jobsCtrl", function($scope, careerData) {

    //get list of countries when app loads
    careerData.countryList().then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.countries = response.data;   
            $scope.countries.unshift({countryCode: "Select a country"}); 
        }, function errorCallback(response) {  
            console.log(response);
    });

    $scope.getRoles = careerData.jobByCountry().then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log(response)
        }, function errorCallback(response) {  
            console.log(response);
    })
});

app.factory('careerData', ['$http', function($http){
return {

     countryList: function() {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'testUrl'
        })
    },

    jobByCountry: function() {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'someurl'
        })
    }
}
}]);
```

Comment: 1st thing add `ng-model` to `select` elemeent then place `ng-change` directive over select element instead of placing it on `option`.

Comment: You can't use events on `<option>`. Not supported cross browser....notably IE and I think Safari

Answer (score 0):

First you should use [**ngOptions**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Change **this**:

```
<select>
  <option ng-change="getRoles()" ng-repeat="country in countries">{{ country.countryCode }}</option>   
</select>
```

**for:**

```
<select ng-options="country as country.countryCode for country in countries" ng-model="countrySelected" ng-change="getRoles()">  
</select>
```

**Example:**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cars = ["Audi", "BMW", "Corolla", "Mercedes"];

    $scope.check = function() {
      console.log($scope.car);
    }
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    Cars:
    <select ng-model="car" ng-options="car for car in cars" ng-change="check()">
       <option value="">Select a car</option>
    </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: from what i can tell this is still firing before change!

Comment: It isn't possible.

Comment: @phantom, check it above, there's no way to the function called before the selection.

Answer (score 0):

so I think you were looking for this

```
(ngModelChange)="getRoles()"
```

in your HTML tag.

this will fire when you change the module it works for most input field I came across here because it doesn't work with mat-select.

this is for angular 7. this is also an old question.

comment:

but I hope this will help you because this is still not answered if the previous answer works accept it.